# 2d array only works if starts with [0][x]

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I am trying to work with a global 2d array but I encountered the issue that I cannot fill/read the array if it is not [0][x], Why is this?

Php code:

```
<div id=<?php echo $dagen[$i];?>>
</div>
<div id=<?php echo $dagen[$i]."1"; ?>>
<td align="center">
<form>
<select name =<?php echo $dagen[$i]."1"; ?> id=<?php echo $dagen[$i]."1"; ?> onchange="weekchange(this, '<?php echo $i ?>','<?php echo $teller ?>','<?php echo $project[$i] ?>');savechange('<?php echo $project[$i] ?>','<?php echo $i ?>', this);"/>
<?php
for ($z = 1; $z < 53; $z++)
{   
?>
<option value=<?php echo $z ?> <?php if($z == $datum) { echo "selected"; } ?>> <?php echo "week: ".$z ?> </option>
<?php
}
?>
```

its about the function  savechange:

`savechange('<?php echo $project[$i] ?>','<?php echo $i ?>', this);`

$project[$i] = my project name

$i = the position of the project

this = Here I take the value out of my dropdown box.

I send these variables to the javascript function savechange():

```
var arr = new Array([]);

function savechange(project, i, thisvalue)
{
var x = i;
alert(x);
arr[x][0] = project;
alert(arr[x][0]);
arr[x][1] = thisvalue.value;
alert(arr[x][1]);
}
```

the variable arr is a global variable.

when I call this function it will only work when the value of x is 0. Also when I look at other examples the have the same issue, like here: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackSRC/zrnr9/. When I fill in a 1 instead of the first 0 it won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var arr = new Array([]);

function savechange(project, i, thisvalue)
{
var x = i;
alert(x);
arr[x] = new Array([]); // Added this one..
arr[x][0] = project;
alert(arr[x][0]);
arr[x][1] = thisvalue.value;
alert(arr[x][1]);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zrnr9/135/

Answer (score 1):

With multidimensional arrays you need to initialize each array.  See this example that I created expanding on your example: http://jsfiddle.net/x1uyL8va/

So in your code before you can start using arr[x] you need to initialize it as an array, e.g. `arr[x] = new Array([]);`

Answer (score 1):

`var arr = new Array([]);`

This line means you are creating a new array, and setting the first and omly element of it to a new Array. This means that `arr[0]` exists (it is the empty array), but not `arr[1]`. There are two ways around this

1. If you know how many elements should be in `arr` (it looks like `$i` is a loop variable so whatever the maximum that goes up to), you can initialize `arr` with `$i` empty arrays:

   ```
   var arr = new Array();
   for(var i = 0; i < <?php echo $i; ?>; i++) {
     arr.push([]);
   }
   ```
2. If you want to make it more dynamic, you can just set `arr[x]` when you need it. This isn't necessarily the best use for arrays tho, because you will potentially get a lot of gaps, if they choose for example `x = 1 then 7 then 203`:

   ```
   function savechange(project, i, thisvalue)
   {
       var x = i;
       alert(x);
       arr[x] = new Array();
       arr[x][0] = project;
       alert(arr[x][0]);
       arr[x][1] = thisvalue.value;
       alert(arr[x][1]);
   }
   ```